# Looping through scope using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

looping through ng-repeat is easy because you have json object and by keys you can loop and collect data as you want. 
My problem here is how to loop through specific scope or input to get values included into ng-repeat but not included into json object?

here is full code :  https://jsfiddle.net/medoo/wgc1my7d/

**explanation**

I have very simple object without keys like this

```
var arr = ["~\\191746.JPG", "~\\191848.JPG", "~\\191908.JPG"];
```

Then, I listed these values in that simply structured table as follow

```
    <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table id="fils">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="oneFile in ShowFiles">
                <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">{{oneFile}}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
                    <input data-ng-model="naming" type="text" style="width: 200px" /> 
                    <%--here is my problem !!!
                    i need to get values of element "input" or scope "naming" which not included with  ShowFiles  --%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input id="save" data-ng-click="save()" type="button" value="Save" />
        <div id="msg"></div>
    </div>


    <script>
    var arr = ["~\\191746.JPG", "~\\191848.JPG", "~\\191908.JPG"];
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.ShowFiles = arr;

        $scope.save = function () {
            var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
            var index = 0;
            $scope.ShowFiles.forEach(function (oneFile, naming) {
                msg.innerHTML =
                msg.innerHTML + 'row #' + (index++) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(oneFile) + ' --- ' + naming + '<br />';
            });
        };
    )};
    </script>
```

All I need, when I press #save button collect all data for two columns whether
 ( included into scope "ShowFiles" such as {{oneFile}} )
OR
( not included into scope "ShowFiles" such as [input data-ng-model="naming"] ) -- "problem here"

To be displayed as the following

**oneFile                 --- naming**
row #0: "~\191746.JPG" --- "Animals"
row #1: "~\191848.JPG" --- "Cars"
row #2: "~\191908.JPG" --- "Friends"

But unfortunatelly naming displays serial numbers like this 0,1,2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, you need to replace your input element tag with this:

```
<input data-ng-model="fileNames[$index]" type="text" style="width: 200px" />
```

and your controller code to this:

```
var arr = ["~\\191746.JPG", "~\\191848.JPG", "~\\191908.JPG"];
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.ShowFiles = arr;
    $scope.fileNames = [];

    $scope.save = function () {
        var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
        $scope.ShowFiles.forEach(function (oneFile, index) {
            msg.innerHTML =
            msg.innerHTML + 'row #' + (index + 1) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(oneFile) + ' --- ' + $scope.fileNames[index] + '<br />';
        });
    };
});
```